# Empty Google WorkSheet causing error: Exception: The number of columns in the range must be at least 1

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My Google App Script will loop through all WorkSheets to find a certain string and will output the row and column it was found on, but as soon as I add a new empty WorkSheet I get the error "Exception: The number of columns in the range must be at least 1." I would like some input on what's causing this issue. Thank you.

```
function doForAllSheets(){
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var allSheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  
  allSheets.forEach(function(sheet){
    if(sheet.getSheetName() !== "Main"){
    sheet.activate();
 
    findValueInRange();
    
    }
  })
}
                     
function findValueInRange () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
      theLastColumn = ss.getLastColumn(),
      theLastRow = ss.getMaxRows();

  //Returns a two dimensional array of both rows and columns
  var values = ss.getRange(1,1,theLastRow,theLastColumn).getValues();

  var i=0,
      rownum=0, 
      thisRow,
      colvalue,
      whatToFind = "testserial",
      j=0;

  for(i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
    thisRow = values[i];

    for (j=1;j<thisRow.length;j++) {
      colvalue = thisRow[j];
      if (colvalue === whatToFind) {
        Logger.log("The string is in row: " + (i + 1) + " and column: " + (j+1));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite function like this:

```
function findValueInRange () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
      theLastColumn = ss.getLastColumn(),
      theLastRow = ss.getMaxRows();
  if( theLastColumn>0) {
  //Returns a two dimensional array of both rows and columns
  var values = ss.getRange(1,1,theLastRow,theLastColumn).getValues();

  var i=0,
      rownum=0, 
      thisRow,
      colvalue,
      whatToFind = "testserial",
      j=0;

  for(i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
    thisRow = values[i];

    for (j=1;j<thisRow.length;j++) {
      colvalue = thisRow[j];
      if (colvalue === whatToFind) {
        Logger.log("The string is in row: " + (i + 1) + " and column: " + (j+1));
      }
    }
  }
  }
}
```